# MariaDB 10.9 denies remote connections

Tags: mariadb

I have a problem after installing MariaDB 10.9 where I cant log-in to the server (remotely). Two servers are at the moment firewalled but port 3306 is wide open. MariaDB is bound to 0.0.0.0 which i can confirm:

```
root@as1:/var/log# netstat -an | grep 3306
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

If i go to the other server, i can confirm it 'sees' as1's SQL:

```
lukasz@as2:~$ telnet as1 3306
Trying X.X.X.X...
Connected to X.X.X.X.
Escape character is '^]'.
5.5.5-10.9.4-MariaDB-1:10.9.4+maria~deb11-log.
```

Back on as1, i have a user called lukasz:

```
+--------+-------------------------------------------+-----------------------+------+
| User   | authentication_string                     | plugin                | Host |
+--------+-------------------------------------------+-----------------------+------+
| lukasz | *839E2E02728DFBA36C0389417509643BFCA1F91C | mysql_native_password | %    |
+--------+-------------------------------------------+-----------------------+------+
1 row in set (0.002 sec).
```

However, when i try to connect from AS2, do AS1, i see:

```
Nov 12 09:34:20 as1 mariadbd[92659]: 2022-11-12  9:34:20 32 [Warning] Access denied for user 'lukasz'@'AS2' (using password: YES)
```

What am i overlooking?. Both servers have the same configuration file. And i am fine connecting from AS1 to AS2, but from AS2 or any other host online, i always get Access Denied from AS1

---

And to add more, if i create new user 'lukasz2'@'%' on AS1, i can log in locally. So so it's only remote issue.

Answer (score 0):

> MariaDB is binded to 0.0.0.0

A typical server usually has at least two networking interfaces.  So in your /etc/my.cnf file it probably looked like:
bind-address = 127.0.0.1

Comment it out.  If you had made it: bind-address = 0.0.0.0

Then according to this link: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/configuring-mariadb-for-remote-client-access/ "the bind-address must refer to a local IP address, or you will receive a fatal error and MariaDB will not start".

Comment: Unfortunately no cigar, after commenting bind-address out, and restarting MariaDB. It's the same thing, Access Danied from AS2 to AS1:

root@as1:/var/log# netstat -an | grep 3306
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:34348         127.0.0.1:3306          TIME_WAIT
tcp6       0      0 :::3306                 :::*                    LISTEN
root@as1:/var/log# grep -r bind-address /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf
#bind-address            = 0.0.0.0